# Decomposing the unitary Haar measure as product of unit vector Haar measures

Tags: random-variables, quantum-computation, haar-measure, quantum-information

Let $\mu_{D}(U)$ be the Haar measure on the D-dimensional Unitary group $U(D)$, where $U \in \mathrm{SU}(D)$ or $U(D)$.
Can we think of this measure as picking first a unit vector according to the vector Haar measure in $D$ dimensions, then picking the second unit vector in the orthogonal subspace according to the vector Haar measure on $D-1$ dimensions, and so on? Namely, can the unitary Haar measure be decomposed as the product of unit vector Haar measures from 1 to D dimensions?
If yes, how is this written formally?

I have looked into QR decomposition but it kind of does things the other way round. Essentially, it uses the Gram-Schmidt process where at first a vector is chosen then it is made orthogonal to the next chosen vector.

Comment: I think the standard QR method (see here: http://home.lu.lv/~sd20008/papers/essays/Random%20unitary%20[paper].pdf) that you mentioned works with your intuition. Pick a random unit vector $u_1\in\mathbb{C}^d$. One way to generate a vector in the subspace orthogonal to $u_1$ is to randomly select $x_2\in\mathbb{C}^d$, then use Gram-Schmidt to turn that into $x_2' = x_2 - \langle x_2,v_1\rangle v_1$ in the desired subspace and normalize it to $u_2 = x_2'/\Vert x_2'\Vert$. The probability that this fails is zero. So the QR method is doing what you described.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by people in the comments QR decomposition indeed answers my question.
The exact claim is actually proven in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1023/B:MAHU.0000040542.56072.ab) (arXiv preprint [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0310338)) at the beginning of page 5.
I will write the proof below for reference.

The construction says that we can choose the unit vector $u_i$ (the $i$-th column of $U = \left(u_1, u_2, ...\right)$) recursively according to the unit vector Haar measure onto the orthogonal subspace of the previously chose unit vectors $u_1$, $...$, $u_{i-1}$.
To prove that this is a unitary Haar measure we need to prove that the distribution of all the vectors is invariant under the action of any fixed unitary $V$, namely that $V u_1$, $V u_2$, $...$ are distributed identically to $u_1$, $u_2$, $...$.
We will use $\sim$ to denote identically distributed variables, namely we will use $V u_i \sim u_i$ to denote that $V u_i$ and $u_i$ are distributed accordingly to the same distribution.

With these preliminaries in place let us start the proof.
We will follow the proof of the paper and prove invariance only for $u_1$ and $u_2$ and them simply say that the invariance for $u_i$ follows in a similar manner (essentially we are leaving the proof by induction for the reader).

Let V be a fixed unitary.
First notice that obviously $V u_1, V u_2 \cdots ,$ are mutually orthogonal (they are the columns of the unitary $VU$).

1. $u_1$. The first vector is trivial: since $u_1$ is a Haar random vector its distribution is left invariant. Hence, $V u_1$ has the same distribution as $u_1$.
2. Let $V_1$ be any unitary that leaves $V u_1$ unchanged, namely such that :
   \begin{align}
   V_1 V u_1 &= V u_1
   \\
   V^{-1} V_1 V  u_1 &= u_1
   \end{align}
   This means $u_1$ is an invariant subspace of $V^{-1} V_1V$ . Recall $u_2$ is chosen uniformly from the subspace orthogonal to $u_1$ and by left invariance of distribution of $u_2$, we have :
   \begin{align}
   V^{-1} V_1 V u_2 & \sim u_2
   \\
   V_1 V u_2 & \sim V u_2
   \end{align}
   Since, $V_{1}$ on the orthogonal subspace of $V u_1$ is arbitrary this means that the distribution of $V u_{2}$ is also left invariant implying Haar distribution.
   This means that $V u_1$ and $V u_2$ are constructed with the same procedure as $u_1$ and $u_2$, meaning their distribution is the same and thus invariant under $V$.
3. This same argument can be repeated for the other vectors $u_3, ...$

This concludes the proof.